# Associations in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I have an app which allows users to add recipes and then select their favourite recipes to view in their member area, I can select a favourite and i am getting the user_id, recipe_id and giving it a favourite_id.

What I would like to do is output the actual recipe to my view (as a favourite), like dish name, country_of_origin etc. I can do this with an actual recipe but not the favourite.Do i need to use has_many_through for this?

My models look like this

User

```
has_many :recipes
has_many :favourites
```

recipe

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :ingredients 
has_many :preperations
has_many :favourites
```

favourites

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :recipe

attr_accessible :user_id, :recipe_id
```

My controller

```
  @favourites = current_user.favourites
```

my link_to post

```
 <%= link_to "Add to favorites",  {:controller => 'favourites', :action => 'create', :recipe_id => r.id}, {:method => :post } %>
```

i can list the current users recipes, this is my contoller for this

```
@recipes = current_user.recipes if current_user.recipes
```

and then output them to the view like so

```
 <% @recipes.each do |r| %>
 <tr>
 <td><%= r.dish_name %></td>
 <td><%= r.country_of_origin %></td>
 <td><%= r.difficulty %></td>
 <td><%= r.preperation_time %></td>
 <td><%= ingredient_names(r.ingredients) %></td>
 <td><%= preperation_steps(r.preperations) %></td>
 <td><%= image_tag r.avatar.url(:thumb)%></td>
 <tr>
```

So if i do this in the view

```
 <li><%= @favourites %></li>
```

I get this outputted

```
 <Favourite id: 16, user_id: 8, recipe_id: 21, created_at: "2012-11-07 20:24:39", updated_at: "2012-11-07 20:24:39">]
```

If i try

```
 <%= @favourites.dish_name %>
```

then i get the error undefined  method dish_name

How do i get the params of the recipe model to show in the view. I do apologise just cant work it out, which should be really easy i guess?

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get undefined dish_name because your Favourite model does not have such attribute.

`@favourites = current_user.favourites` returns an array of Favourite objects.

In your view you would do something like

```
 <% @favourites.each do |f| %>
   <%= f.recipe %>
 <% end %>
```

That will display all the recipes your current_user favorites. You could narrow it down to display a specific recipe or what not.

Comment: I see what you are saying, makes sense as i have to get the params from the recipe model, thank you clearing that up, however i now get undefined method recipe... what you suggested is the view yes?

Comment: That's correct. I see, the reason why it's giving you an undefined method recipe is becasue what you get from current_user.favourites is an array of Favourite. What you need to do is iterate through the array and then you'll be able to do what you wanted. Let me update my answer

Answer (score 1):

The favorites is just holding the relationship.
You can access the recipe by

```
@favourites.recipe
```

which will then be a recipe object and contain your attributes like dish_name etc.

Comment: I see what you are saying, makes sense as i have to get the params from the recipe model, thank you clearing that up, however i now get undefined method recipe... what you suggested is the view yes?

Answer (score 1):

@favourites is an array, yes? Then you must loop through @favourites and work with each element individually as so:

```
<% @favourites.each do |favorite| %>
  <%= favorite.recipe.dish_name %>    
<% end %>
```